# Bash script checking if specific Canon printer is online

Tags: bash, printing, canon

Objective: Create a bash script that checks if a certain Canon printer is connected and online (connected: true/false)

How can I do this in the terminal (or via python)? I have tried `lpstat -p -d` but that gives "printer idle" even though it is turned off.

It is a wifi connected printer, so maybe I could ping it?

Comment: Please post your last edit as an answer as it's not possible to see that you've found a way without reading your question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this command `cnijnetprn --search auto` and it gave the following output:

```
network cnijnet:/18-0C-AC-2E-EF-87 "Canon iP7200 series" "Canon-iP7200-series_18-0C-AC-2E-EF-87"
```

If the printer is not online then I don't get any output.

I think I could use that.

Comment: Did you check the return value of that program? It might be easier to work with that than to check for non-empty program output.